# parfor not giving speed ups

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I am using parfor of matlab parallel toolbox to see if that boosts my code's speed. However, I don't see any difference in speed. I tried with very simple to complex loop body. But I don't see any difference.

The simplest I tried was

```
parfor i=:1000000
   [i]
end

The more time consuming one

parfor i=1:1000000
   pcg(A,b); %solve system of linear equations with huge A matrix(definitely time consuming)
end
```

But I don't see any speedups. What should I do? Where might it go wrong?

Comment: How many cores do you have? Have you established a pool of workers? Are you certain that the `pcg` function isn't already optimized to work on multiple cores?

Comment: @Dan. I am not sure if a single call to pcg is optimized to use multiple cores at once. I have four cores.

Comment: As previous commenter has mentioned, you have to use the command matlabpool to specify how many processes you would like to create